# Spring.NET Expression that References an Object Definition

Tags: c#, configuration, expression, spring.net, spring-el

I'm trying to reference another object I've defined in a Spring config file from within an expression.  Specifically, I'm trying to populate a property with the value of an expression where I call a method and then a property on the object returned from that method.

I've tried the following (names have been changed):

```xml
<property name="NullableIntProperty"
          expression="#{Some.Object.Id}.Get().NullableIntValue"/>
```

where `Some.Object.Id` is a reference to another object I have defined in a config file such as:

```xml
<object id="Some.Object.Id" ... >
```

but my app fails to start with the parsing exception `expecting "COLON", found '}'`.  I think it's expecting a namespace, but I'm not finding the documentation for this.

I've tried several things, but everywhere I hit a dead end.  I originally tried a combination of the `MethodInvokingFactoryObject` and `PropertyRetrievingFactoryObject` which we use in other places for non-nullable types, but this fails for nullables that are actually `null` since Spring sees an object factory returning `null` as a failure (which it usually is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@(object-id-here)` expression syntax to [retrieve an object from the Spring context using an expression](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-object-references):

```xml
<property name="NullableIntProperty"
          expression="@(Some.Object.Id).PropertyOnSomeObject"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing # to $ should fix it, I believe.