# IoC spring.net injecting System.Type

Tags: inversion-of-control, spring.net, system.type

I am trying to initiate a class that is expecting a System.Type in it's CTOR.

Is there a way in spring.net config file to accomplish this, and preferable pass the type of a spring initialised object?

Thanks,

Lihnid

Comment: I saw you accepted Sebastian's answer. His answer is correct, but doesn't give you the type of a spring managed object, like you asked. I've updated my answer to show an approach to achieve that more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this should do it:

```
<constructor-arg name="argumentname" expression="T(namespace.to.my.type, assemblyname)" />
```

Comment: That would work; assembly name is optional, but good to put in.

Answer (score 4):

This also works:

```
<constructor-arg name="argumentname" value="MyNamespace.MyType, MyAssembly"/>
```

Use VS2010 Add-In for intellisense:
http://www.springframework.net/vsaddin/

Comment: nice! I didn't know that it was possible without expressions

Comment: @bbaia: That's nice to know. Does spring.net delegate this to .NET's [TypeNameConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.typenameconverter.aspx)? How come this works without registering a `TypeConverter`? `System.Type` isn't decorated with `TypeConverter(typeof(TypeNameConverter))` [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx).

Comment: @Marijn: check classes "RuntimeTypeConverter" and "TypeConverterRegistry" in Spring.Core.TypeConversion namespace.

Comment: @Marijn: related documentation: http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-type-conversion

Comment: Ah, it's the first one in the list of built-in type converters. I always miss the first one in the list :).

Answer (score 3):

You can use an expression to inject a type:

```xml
<!-- use an expression to specify type -->
<constructor-arg type="System.Type, mscorlib" 
                 expression="T(MyNameSpace.MySecondClass)" />
```

To get the type of a spring-managed object, you can use the `expression="@(object-id-here)"` [syntax to use a spring-managed object in your expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406925/spring-net-expression-that-references-an-object-definition/6762523#6762523) and simply call `GetType()` on it:

```xml
<!-- inject the type of MySecondObject, configured elsewhere -->
<constructor-arg type="System.Type, mscorlib" 
                 expression="@(MySecondObject).GetType()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if anyone is wondering how to do this with using the System.Type as the dictionary key.

```
<object id="myDictionary" type="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary&lt;System.Type,string&gt;">
    <constructor-arg name="dictionary">
        <dictionary key-type="System.Type" value-type="string">
            <entry value="myStringValue">
                <key>
                    <expression value="T(namespace.to.MyClassType)"></expression>
                </key>
            </entry>
        </dictionary>
    </constructor-arg>
</object>
```